# How can I make clearThemingColors() work on Viewer 6.4.0 and upwards?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a code to switch all the lines in a 2D drawing on Forge Viewer to black, by applying a theme (as described in the blog), and reverting the original colors. But the 6.4.0 version of the Viewer broke something when reverting, and now all the lines stay white instead. All versions up to 6.3.5 work. Did something change that needs new code to make this work?

This is what I do today, that worked before flawlessly, but doesn't now:

```
  color2D.onClick = function (e) {

    if (blackWiteToggle) {
      window._viewerSecondary.impl.toggleSwapBlackAndWhite(false);
      paint2DToBlackAndWhite(_viewerSecondary);
      blackWiteToggle = false;
    } else {
      window._viewerSecondary.impl.toggleSwapBlackAndWhite(true);
      window._viewerSecondary.clearThemingColors();
      window._viewerSecondary.restoreState(stateDefalult);
      blackWiteToggle = true;
    }
  };

function paint2DToBlackAndWhite(viewerToPaint) {
  var frags = viewerToPaint.model.getFragmentList().fragments.fragId2dbId;
  frags.forEach(function(frag){
    frag.forEach(function(dbId){
      if (dbId < 0) return;
      viewerToPaint.setThemingColor(dbId, new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1), viewerToPaint.model)
    });
  });
}
```

What happened before: the drawing has colors originally. When the user presses the button, all the lines get black color theme applied to them (and white background, but not relevant to the problem). When the user presses again, the theme colors are cleared, and the 2D drawing gets colored again.

What happens after 6.4.0: the lines get the black color theme correctly. When the user presses again, all lines become white, when they should have the original colors reverted.

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue with Viewer v6.5. However with v6.4+ you can apply colors recursively so to paint the entire model simply do `viewer.setThemingColor(model.getRootId(),color,model,true)`. And you can check if the original color vectors are recorded correctly via `model.getInstanceTree().fragList.db2ThemingColor`. Can you send thru the model to forge.help@autodesk.com (via a sharing service e.g. weTransfer/Dropbox) for us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: On further investigation, I discovered that `model.getFragmentList().fragments.dbId2fragId` is an array on 6.3-, and an object in 6.4+. So, the later versions can't call `.length` on it, on `FragmentList.prototype.clearThemingColors`.

Running a diff on both viewer versions, this has changed: `svf.fragments.dbId2fragId = {};` (was `[]`). `clearThemingColors` is the only method that uses `.length` on it, and didn't change.

Comment: I'll send this issue to forge.help@autodesk, it should be better to treat it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Our Engineering is looking into this and will fix the issue in the upcoming release soon as possible.

In the meantime for anyone runs into the same issue here's a piggyback workaround that our OP Tiago has come up with:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.prototype.clearThemingColors = function 
(model) { 
// use default RenderModel by default 
model = model || this.model;

model.getFragmentList().fragments.dbId2fragId.length = 
Object.keys(model.getFragmentList().fragments.dbId2fragId).length;

model.clearThemingColors();

// we changed the scene to apply theming => trigger re-render 
this.impl.invalidate(true); 
};
```